# Join and exclude

Tags: sql, linq-to-sql

My table structure has a nullable ID field ParentId that can be mapped by back to Id of the table to create a hierarchy. ParentId is nullable. I want to be able to get the Ids with the parent data and I want all data where the Parent is null. But, I don't want the rows where the Parent is not null returned 2x.

What type of join can I use for this?

Below is an example of what I'd like returned:

```
Id 1 ParentId 2 -> ID 2 ParentId Null
Id 3 ParentId Null -> NULL
```

Note, if the ParentId has an ID then I don't want it returned as a row but skipped. The following is INCORRECT because Id 2 is included twice. It should only be included on the right side and not as an item on the left side.

```
Id 1 ParentId 2 -> ID 2 ParentId Null
Id 2 ParentId Null
Id 3 ParentId Null
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
SELECT t.ID, t.thingName, t.parentID, pt.thingName as parentName
FROM things t
LEFT JOIN things pt on pt.id = t.parentID
```

I set up an example on SQL Fiddle ([link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/43c6c/4)).

**UPDATED:** Changed to LEFT JOIN so that records that have no parents still show up. As you requested, rows where parentID is not NULL will only be returned once. If this is still not what you're looking for, please clarify.

Comment: Okay, I don't want ANY rows returned twice. So, if a row is a parent row then I don't want that row returned as a child row.

Comment: I believe the sample query that I supplied meets your requirements, doesn't it?

Comment: No, because it includes Parent Rows that were already appended to child rows. It should not return left rows that were included in the right join.